# Problema al obtener consulta sql con php

Tags: php, sql, base-de-datos, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Cuando hago la consulta e intento imprimir una consulta sql en una tabla con php simplemente no lo hace. Cuando hago la consulta desde phpmyadmin si me muestra los resultados

```
<?php

                    $con=new mysqli("localhost","root","","biblioteca");

                    $nom=$_POST['Nombre']."%";
                    $apell=$_POST['Apellido']."%";
                    $lib=$_POST['Libro']."%";
                    $fec=date("Y-m-d",strtotime($_POST['Fecha']))."%";
                    $cor=$_POST['Correo']."%";
                    $tel=$_POST['Telefono']."%";
                    $tip=$_POST['Tipo'];


                    $query=$con->query("SELECT Nombre, Apellido, Titulo, dev, Correo, Telefono, Tipo FROM lectores, libros, rel_lec_lib WHERE lectores.ID_lec=rel_lec_lib.ID_lec AND libros.ID_lib=rel_lec_lib.ID_lib AND Nombre LIKE '$nom' AND Apellido LIKE '$apell' AND Titulo LIKE '$lib' AND dev LIKE '$fec' AND Correo LIKE '$cor' AND Telefono LIKE '$tel' AND Tipo='$tip'");

                    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
                        $fecha=date("d-m-Y",strtotime($row['dev']));
                ?>  
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row['Nombre']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['Apellido']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['Titulo']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $fecha; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['Correo']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['Telefono']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['Tipo']; ?></td>
                </tr>      
                   <?php }?>
```

Answer (score 0):

El error era que cuando no se seleccionaba una fecha, esta automaticamente la asumia como

> 1970-01-01

solo tuve que corregir:

```
$fec=date("Y-m-d",strtotime($_POST['Fecha']))."%";
```

Y dejarlo:

```
$fec=date("Y-m-d",strtotime($_POST['Fecha']));
```

Por ultimo agregar:

```
if ($fec=="1970-01-01") {
                        $fec="%";
                    }
```